# Designing model for Storm Topology

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, apache-storm, maintainability

I am using Apache Kafka & Apache Storm integration.
I need to design a model.Here are the specification of my topology :

I have configured topic in Kafka. Let say **customer1** . Now, the storm bolts will read the data from the **customer1** kafka-spout. It processes the data and writes into mongo and cassandra db. Here the db names are also same as the kafka topics **customer1**. Table structure and rest of the things will be same.

Now, suppose I get a new customer let say **customer2**. I need to read data from **customer2** kafka-spout and write it into mongo and cassandra db where the db names will be **customer2**.

I can think of two ways to do it .

1. I will write a bolt which gets trigged whenever a new customer name gets added into a Kafka topic .That bolt will have code  which will create and submit the new topology to cluster.
2. I will create independent jars for all the customer and submit the topology manually.

I searched a lot about it but didn't get which approach is better.

What are the PROs and CONs of the above specified approach in terms of efficiency, code maintainability and adding new changes to the existing model ?

Is there any other way to handle this ?

Comment: Given the nature of the transformations is the same what about create a topology which will take the topic name and db name as parameter? This is a single jar, which will change the name of the topology, zookeper folder, zookeper client id and db name based on the parameters you give it? And submit the always the same jar ?

Comment: Yeah.Got it .Thanks a lot !!